# Creating Bootstrap 4 input-group with beta 3 prepend/append not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I created a input group in Bootstrap 4 **Beta 3**. 
Since [Beta 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) I have to use the `input-group-append` and `input-group-prepend` classes.
But I do not know how to use these classes at the end of my input group.
 The last button in my input group has no rounded edge at the end - or in my second exampe too much rounded edges - or in the third example a massive outline.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  First try
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B4</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  second try
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B3</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B4</button>
  </div>

  third try
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">B4</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you use them:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, to break this down, you first have a div with the class `input-group`.

Then you put a div with the class `input-group-prepend` inside the first div.

Then, inside that `input-group-prepend` div you put a span with the class `input-group-text` and an id of your choice.

Then you create an input element as a **sibling** to the div the class `input-group-prepend` and add `aria-describedby="basic-addon1"` to that input element. Whereas `basic-addon1` needs to be replaced with the id you had chosen in the previous step.

And when appending, the div with the class `input-group-append` comes as a sibling *after* your input element.

And when adding a button you do it like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once again, the div with the class `input-group-append` comes as a sibling AFTER the previous input element. And inside that div you put your button.

So, basically, there's just one simple rule to remember:

A div with the class `input-group-prepend` must be added as **sibling BEFORE** your input element. 
And a div with the class `input-group-append` must be added as **sibling AFTER** your input element.

And then you put whatever you want inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use simply use prepend before  & append after where you need them.

Like below Snippet-

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
     <label>Search</label>
  <div class="input-group">

    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" >@</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" >$</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >#</button>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Search"  >

    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >@</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" >$</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" >#</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```