# Bootstrap input-group-prepend not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am following the official documentation and looking at many examples and the same problems to other people but I do not see any solution to this.

In the official documentation is shown correctly, example that I am seeing is the following
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#basic-example

I copy and paste the following code from the official documentation

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

version bootstrap:

> Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 (https://getbootstrap.com)
>
> Copyright 2011-2017
>
> The Bootstrap Authors Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.  icensed under
>
> MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)

The code is not shown as in the official page, it just does not work, I have managed to make it work with **input-group-addon** but I would like to know why it does not work with the code of the official website since I am using the same version of bootstrap.

I have also followed this thread without any solution:
[Creating Bootstrap 4 input-group with beta 3 prepend/append not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221504/creating-bootstrap-4-input-group-with-beta-3-prepend-append-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 Beta2, the class name was `input-group-addon`

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/qJ5GDNQqb3 (Bootstrap 4 Beta 2)

Now that Bootstrap 4.0.0 is here, the class name is `input-group-prepend` which is what is shown in the docs. **The docs are for 4.0.0**, not 4.0 Beta 2.

https://www.codeply.com/go/o7QZ2u7eCX (Bootstrap 4.0.0)

Either upgrade to Bootstrap 4.0.0, or use `input-group-addon` for Bootstrap 4.0 Beta 2